# Regarding the definition of the entire modular forms

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, modular-group

I was reading the Wiki page of the Modular Forms https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form
In the definition, the function is assumed to be holomorphic at all cusps, then the entire modular form is defined to be holomorphic at the cusp.
In this case all modular forms are entire.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @WhatsUp In this case all modular forms are entire. Or there is a mistake in the definition of the modular form.

Comment: It's just a different definition. I believe most people use the definition in Wiki, i.e. a "modular form" is supposed to be holomorphic on all cusps, while the non-holomorphic ones are called "modular functions". The terms used in the picture you are linking is somewhat non-standard.

Comment: @WhatsUp where can the standard definition be found?

Comment: I see, the linked image was from wiki... Then I'd recommend Milne's notes: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/mf.html

Comment: Nobody uses the word entire modular form because modular forms are functions on the upper half-plane and entire is for functions extending to (and analytic on) the whole of $\Bbb{C}$.