# The modular and entire modular forms for a subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, modular-group

Let $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ be the modular group and $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

I think that it is well-known that a function $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called a modular form for the subgroup $\Gamma$ of weight $k$ if:

1. $f(g(z)) = (cz+d)^k f(z)$, for all $z \in \mathbb{H}, g\in \Gamma$.
2. $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{H}$.
3. $f$ is holomorphic at the cusps of $\Gamma$.

Now, How is the **entire** modular form for the subgroup $\Gamma$ defined?

Comment: There are no entire modular forms, this term doesn't exist.

Comment: @reuns I have seen it many times in different references.

Comment: I too have never seen the term "entire modular forms" and I'm pretty surprised by the Wikipedia page containing that term, but certainly notations around these things vary. According to the Wiki reference in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060119/regarding-the-definition-of-the-entire-modular-forms), what you've defined would be an ''entire'' modular form. A ''non-entire'' modular form would involve weakening condition 3.

Comment: The point is that for each cusp of $\Gamma$, by taking the Fourier expansion around that cusp, you get a different $q$-expansion of $f$. It's quite possible that $f$ will be holomorphic at one cusp, but not at another.